# ES6 imports multiple times when symbolic links are used

Tags: javascript, linux, ecmascript-6, import, symlink

I'm on Linux and use ECMAScript6.

Here is my file system (A, B and C are directories).

```
A -> a.js
  -> C -> c.js
B -> b.js
  -> symbolic link (called C) to C
```

In a.js and b.js there is `import class_C from './C/c.js'`.

I can see in the developer's window of my browser that c.js is loaded twice.

For performance reasons, I would like to load c.js only once.

How could I do (keeping my symbolic link) ?

Comment: Can you show the ACTUAL code?  Modules are cached, but they are cached by filename reference so if you load by symbolic link one place, but not another, then the caching system may not know that they are both the same file and may load each one separately.

Comment: Only the import code ? The whole files ? Filename reference OK ; so, is there a way to import by real path ?

Comment: Well, I want to see the two import statements in appropriate context and see the paths you're using and see if one is a symbolic link and the other is not?  Why are you using a symbolic link in the first place?  Perhaps that's the real problem to be solved here?

Comment: Yes, one is symbolic and the other is not. Symbolic links are a (unusual) design choice. I've tried to give a relational structure to folders (instead of hierarchical).

Comment: Well, you've discovered that the module cache is not aware of a symbolic link so it doesn't recognize it as the same module you're importing and thus it imports it again.  You'll either have to stop using the symbolic link or live with the module being loaded twice.  Those are your choices.

Comment: FYI, I think nodejs has some ability to implement a custom loader so perhaps you could replace the existing module loader with your own, if your motivations really justify that work.

Comment: Node ? My code is client-side. Is there no way to use a custom-designed function in an import statement (I've tried but got an error) ?

Comment: Oh, client-side?  No options there for a custom loader.  Either change your URLs to be the same or live with the module loading more than once.  There is no ability for the client to have any idea that two separate URLs will internally resolve to the same file on the server.  That is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading `c.js` from two different URLs that your server somehow knows point to the same file, then there's just no way for the client to know that those two different URLs point at the same module.  As such, it loads each separately.

The module loader has a cache built-in, but the only way the cache knows it's the same module being loaded a second time is if it has the same fully qualified URL.  If you're loading two separate URLs from the client, then the module loader thinks those are two separate modules and loads each one separately.

Your only client-side option to prevent double loading is to use the same URL for both imports.

You can use relative URLs as long as the relative URLs turn into the same fully qualified URLs when the loader builds the full URL to request from your server.  It is the fully qualified URL that determines whether you get a cache match or not or whether it launches a separate load.

Comment: It seems to be possible to dynamically import and export: https://webreflection.medium.com/javascript-dynamic-import-export-b0e8775a59d4. I inspect and post a solution if I find. Just to tell not to close the topic.

Comment: It's possible but syntactically too heavy. I resign. But I regret that there is dynamic export in Javascript/ECMAScript.

Comment: @Zlotz - I'm not sure what dynamically importing has to do with your question at all.  You're importing two different URLs.  The browser has no way of knowing those are the same module.  The same would be true with dynamically importing too.

Comment: I had the idea of conditioning my import statements with something like `if (typeof <class or function I want to import> === 'undefined')`. To detect identical files, the browser could do just like the server does when PHP function `include_once` is used.

Comment: @Zlotz - That could work if you were testing global symbols though it is better to avoid globals whenever possible.  I still don't understand why you think you have to use different URLs for the imports?  That seems to be the root problem.

Comment: It was just a design choice. I have the (very personal) feeling that files structures are relational in the way we use them, not hierarchical. Less abstractly, If a folder needs another folder, why not linking them instead of going back each time to the root or using relative paths beginning with ../../../

Comment: Moreover this conception reflects more what goes on in the machine (with pointers)

Comment: Well, your notion of how you want to use lots of different URLs to all point to the same module is going against the grain of how the underlying module cache works.  So, you're attempting to swim against the tide and you will have this issue in every single project you write that uses this scheme.  Your choice if you really think that design leads you to better and more maintainable code, but it's certainly not a direction I would go.  I'd much rather come up with a design that was in harmony with the underlying module loading architecture rather than in direct conflict with it.

Comment: And, FYI, I've never had to import files with `../../../ ` myself.  So, something else you're doing is leading you to that.  I tend to use a wide and shallow directory hierarchy (which fits well with putting things in lots of independent modules), not narrow and deep.

Comment: OK. Neither have I, I use absolute paths from now.

Comment: @Zlotz - If this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.